# NextJS Heroku Build Fail

Tags: reactjs, heroku, next.js

I just created a new Heroku project and tried to deploy my master branch for the first time. The build fails with this error:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.18.0...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.15
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       added 298 packages in 7.196s
       
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > nextjs@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_6948ab0e
       > next build
       
       info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: no next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
       warn  - No build cache found. Please configure build caching for faster rebuilds. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-cache
       Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
       This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
       You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
       https://nextjs.org/telemetry
       
       info  - Checking validity of types...
       info  - Creating an optimized production build...
       info  - Compiled successfully
       info  - Collecting page data...
       info  - Generating static pages (0/3)
Client warn: request fail { code: 'unauthorized', message: 'API token is invalid.' }
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
APIResponseError: API token is invalid.
    at Object.buildRequestError (/tmp/build_6948ab0e/node_modules/@notionhq/client/build/src/errors.js:79:20)
    at Client.request (/tmp/build_6948ab0e/node_modules/@notionhq/client/build/src/Client.js:206:43)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async getDatabase (/tmp/build_6948ab0e/.next/server/pages/index.js:34:20)
    at async getStaticProps (/tmp/build_6948ab0e/.next/server/pages/index.js:115:20)
    at async renderToHTML (/tmp/build_6948ab0e/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/render.js:28:1780)
    at async /tmp/build_6948ab0e/node_modules/next/dist/export/worker.js:26:6
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/tmp/build_6948ab0e/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584)
       info  - Generating static pages (3/3)
> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /
    at /tmp/build_6948ab0e/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:31:1106
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/tmp/build_6948ab0e/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584)
    at async /tmp/build_6948ab0e/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:45:49
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/tmp/build_6948ab0e/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584)
    at async /tmp/build_6948ab0e/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:27:1475
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/tmp/build_6948ab0e/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nextjs@0.1.0 build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nextjs@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.kDCJD/_logs/2021-10-01T18_50_38_886Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Has anyone seen this kind of error? "APIResponseError: API token is invalid". The app runs perfectly when I run it locally (including making API requests) and it builds with `next build`. It's just on Heroku it's not deploying. Why might this be? I'm using React and NextJS.

Comment: Are the environment variables properly set up in Heroku? Could you provide some code related to the API calls you make?

Comment: Ahh, that was it! My env variables were not set up. Thank you!!